# How can I add a bunch of png's to a Class of cards in Pygame?

Tags: python, oop, pygame, playing-cards

So I have learned how to make a deck of cards with various functions through a course I am taking. Now, I would like to create a deck that can be used in the pygame window using the class I have made and my file of `png`. When I run the various functions e.x. `deal_card()`, it returns a card in the format '4 of Clubs', so I know it works. How can I get those to actually represent the `png` of card images that I have?

```
import pygame
import os
from random import shuffle

# Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()


# Setting up the screen and background
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


# Title and Icon of window
pygame.display.set_caption("Blackjack")

icon = pygame.image.load('card-game.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def __repr__(self):
        # return "{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit)
        return f"{self.value} of {self.suit}"



class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
        values = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
        self.cards = [Card(value, suit) for suit in suits for value in values]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Deck of {self.count()} cards"

    def count(self):
        return len(self.cards)

    def _deal(self, num):
        count = self.count()
        actual = min([count,num])
        if count == 0:
            raise ValueError("All cards have been dealt")
        cards = self.cards[-actual:]
        self.cards = self.cards[:-actual]
        return cards

    def deal_card(self):
        return self._deal(1)[0]

    def deal_hand(self, hand_size):
        return self._deal(hand_size)

    def shuffle(self):
        if self.count() < 52:
            raise ValueError("Only full decks can be shuffled")
        shuffle(self.cards)
        return self



# Game Loop that ensures window is always running.
# We make sure we do our stuff in this loop
running = True
while running:

    # RGB
    screen.fill((50,0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    # RGB
    screen.fill((50,0,0))
```

Comment: What have you tried or thought about doing so far? If your PNGs use a consistent naming convention, you could just generate a name based on the current card and just pick the image from your card images folder that has that name. Any reason you haven't tried that?

Comment: I am quite new to this so I don't really know how to conceptually go about doing something like this. The PNG's are named: 2 of Clubs, K of Hearts etc. PS. this is a personal project and I am just trying to learn as much as I can without following somebody on Youtube

Comment: In that case, `pygame.image.load(str(card) + '.png')` should work for getting the image, since your cards'  `__repr__` is in the same format as your card images' names. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> The PNG's are named: 2 of Clubs, K of Hearts etc.

The file name of the card corresponds to the "official" string representation of the card ([`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)). Extend the name by the file extension (`.png`) and use [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) to load the card image:

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

        self.image = pygame.image.load(str(self) + '.png')

    def __repr__(self):
        # return "{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit)
        return f"{self.value} of {self.suit}"
```